# jquery autocomplete ghost image

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have an input that is autocomplete. When I enter a value into the input I get a list and at the bottom of the list it tells me how many records it found, matching my criteria. After I select a value from the list, the list will disappear and fill the control, but it leaves an image of the selected value under the control.

[image]

Why does this happen and how do I fix it?

This is my code that returns the results:

```
function FillClinicsByName() {
    if ($('#txtClinicName').val() == '') {
        $('#txtClinicName').autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    async: false,
                    delay: 250,
                    url: "WebService1.asmx/ClinicName",
                    data: "{'Name':'" + request.term.replace(/'/g, "\&apos") + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                            return {
                                label: item.split('|')[0],
                                val: item.split('|')[1]
                            }    // end of return
                        }))    // end of response
                    }   // end of success
                });     // end of ajax
            },   // end of source
            select: function (e, i) {
                $('#hdfldClinic').val(i.item.val);
            },
            change: function (event, ui) {
                if (!ui.item) {
                    $(event.target).val('');
                }
            },
            minLength:1
        });     // end of autocomplete
    }   // nothing in the text box
}
```

I am using jquery-1.10.2.js and bootstrap 3 and vs2015

Comment: You can use the code snippet tool to create a working version of your code, just press CTRL+M while you are editing your post. You can even link your own files.

It is otherwise hard for us to understand and help you fix your problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I had to guess you aren't including the CSS for a jQuery UI theme. A quick fix is to add this class to your CSS:

```
.ui-helper-hidden-accessible {
    display: none;
}
```

This stuff is added to the page to help screen readers for accessibility. The best thing to do is to copy jQuery's class definition at least since setting it display none will make screen readers ignore it. The CSS is as follows:

```
.ui-helper-hidden-accessible {
    border: 0;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    height: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
}
```

I believe you can also programmatically turn this stuff off but I am not 100% sure on how to do it and do not think it is apart of their API.

Comment: It was the theme.css that I was missing.